# get decimal part of number in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do you access the decimal part of a number in MS Access? More specifically I want only the component after the decimal point, but not including the decimal point. This must also work for all whole numbers. I've seen this answered for other SQL engines, but they don't work in Access. I can't be much more specific than this because of the sensitive nature of what I'm actually working on.

For example given the following numbers the input is on the left and the output is on the right. Output can be either text or a number.

```
Source   Correct  Incorrect1  Incorrect2
10.0     0        0.0         .0
3.14159  14159    0.14159     .14159
45.65    65       0.65        .65
173.0    0        0.0         .0
143.15   15       0.15        .15
```

If I was using C# the following code would give me what I want:

```
private string getDecimalComponent(double input)
{
    String strInput = input.ToString();
    if (strInput.Contains('.'))
    {
        return strInput.Split('.')[1];
    }
    else
    {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: What **specifically** "does not work in Access"?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. 3.14 without the decimal is 3, and the numbers to the right are .14. You can't "remove the decimal point" without either converting to a string or doing math (multiplying by 100, for instance). 0.049 without the decimal would become .049 * 1000, or 49 - note it is **not** 049. What **exactly** are you trying to do? Are you trying to convert the decimal portion into a whole number, or are you trying to extract it as a string without the decimal point? If you cannot clearly state your question, we can't answer it and you're wasting our time.

Comment: I want to split 3.14 into 2 separate parts. They should respectively be 3 and 14. If this was PHP, the explode function with '.' as the delimiter would give me exactly what I want. Since 3.04 should be 3 and "04" (not 4) respectively, treating the whole thing as a string would be fine.

Comment: After thinking about it, I would probably be ok with 4 or "4" instead of "04". However the output can't contain the actual decimal point.

Comment: Argh! This is like visiting the dentist! What **output** are you trying to get **specifically**? A number? A string? You need to [edit] your question and explain **exactly** what you're asking us to help you do. Note the key phrases **specifically** and **exactly**. If you're not going to cooperate and ask an actual question, just delete it and quit wasting people's time here.

Comment: I'm trying to split a list of numbers that have decimal points into 2 components. The integer portion and the decimal portion, but have the decimal portion be displayed as a whole number. I already have the integer portion by using the Int function. In the number 3.14 I would need the value either 14 (integer) or "14" string. It doesn't matter to me which one.

Comment: In a similar manner getting the components of an IP address is not too different than what I'm trying to do. Take 192.168.0.1 I would need the numbers 192, 168, 0, and 1. If you were to truncate that down to just 192.168, I would need 192 (which I already have) and 168 as either an integer or a string. I don't know how else to say this since I felt the original post made it clear I'm asking for the decimal component of a number represented as a whole number.

Comment: Thank you for the edit to clearly state the question. I've voted to reopen based on the improved quality and clarity of your post.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract the integer portion of the value.

Example:
4.25 - Int(4.25) = 0.25

Or, as a sample SQL expression:

```
SELECT
    [myDecimalNumber],
    [myDecimalNumber] - Int([myDecimalNumber]) as [rightOfDecimal]
FROM tableA
```

Comment: I need either 25 or "25" not 0.25, "0.25", or ".25".

Comment: then take the output, convert to string using `cStr`, and remove the decimal by using `replace()`.

Comment: So I tried SELECT Mid(CStr(4.1-Int(4.1)),3) and it works, but if I try SELECT Mid(CStr(4.0-Int(4.0)),3) it gives me blank instead of 0. That's the closest I've gotten it so far.

Comment: `SELECT Replace(CStr(4.1-Int(4.1)),".","")`

Comment: If I add a Val to that it works. SELECT Val(Replace(CStr(4.1-Int(4.1)),".","")) and SELECT Val(Replace(CStr(4.0-Int(4.0)),".","")) both work correctly.

Comment: Maybe not when I manually put in numbers it works, but in several cases I get what appear to be precession errors.

Comment: what is the datatype of the numbers you are dealing with?

Comment: Number with Field Size set to Double, Format set to 0.0.

Comment: SELECT Val(cStr(7.1))-Int(Val(cStr(7.1))) successfully reproduces my error without using the table itself. I've also confirmed the error occurs it the subtraction part only.

Comment: That's because you're trying to subtract an `int` from a `string`. Try: `SELECT CInt(Val(cStr(7.1)))-CInt(Val(cStr(7.1)))`

Comment: This is the complete expression: SELECT Replace(CStr(Val(cStr(7.1))-Int(Val(cStr(7.1)))),".","")

Comment: Same issue as in my previous comment.

Comment: I found a way to simplify it without making it as confusing as it was. This also produces the same error: SELECT CDbl('7.1') - CInt('7.1') The result should be 0.1, but instead I get 9.99999999999996E-02

Comment: It looks like you can fix that by rounding to 1 decimal place. But what if you don't know its supposed to be only 1 decimal place?

Comment: You need to stop performing operations on different types. In this case, you are subtracting and integer from a double. Access will try to coerce the execution of the operation, and you will get an error. Just make sure the 2 types are the same. In this case, you want both to be of type `double`

Comment: In order to get the decimal component of a number that's what you have to do. I figured out how to show you what's happening with the exact original formula: SELECT CDbl(7.1) AS Input, Val(Replace(CStr(Input-Int(Input)),".","")) The cast at the beginning is simply to convert it into a format not that unlike what would be stored in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
       SELECT 3.14%1 AS mycolumn from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the circumstance.  If this is, for instance, in a textbox, you can use InStr to find the decimal, and then use the Mid() function to get the number after it.  If it's part of an arithmetic equation, then I would use the Int() function and subtract one number from the other to get the difference.

If you can elaborate on how it's being used, and in what context, I can edit my answer to give you more specifics.

EDIT: After more info came to light, try this:

```
Public Function GetParts(Temp1 as Double)

Temp2 = Int(Temp1) 
Temp3 = Mid(Temp1, InStr(Temp1, ".") + 1) 

MsgBox Temp2 
MsgBox Temp3 

End Function
```

Comment: The value is stored as a number with at least 1 decimal place. The result of the loss of integer component needs to look like an integer. For example 3.14 -> "14". In the case of something like 3.04 the result would have to be "04" which isn't quite the same as 4.

Comment: After thinking about it "04" vs 4 probably wouldn't make a difference. Either would be acceptable.

Comment: That's closer, but it fails in 1 case. Anything where the decimal is 0. Such as 17.0 should return 0 and in this case it returns 17. Unfortunately I can't be anymore specific due to the sensitive nature of what I'm working on.

Comment: I'm actually buried at work (yes, I actually have a full-time job, I don't get paid for this...), but I'd suggest adding some code to test if it's an Integer.  If it is, format it as 0.0 (as opposed to #.#, which will not force a zero) and then run Temp3 against it.  If not, just run Temp3.

Comment: I though adding Val() would help, but it doesn't. I still get the original number in the event of no decimal component

Comment: This is oversimplified because it assumes dot to be decimal separator, what is not true in many environments.

Answer (score 0):

### A stable solution producing String containing decimal places from Double.

```vb
SELECT DecimalPlaces(MyColumn) FROM MyTable
```

where the above user-defined function contains the following code:

```vb
Function DecimalPlaces(ByVal value As Double) As String

  Dim intPartLen As String
  intPartLen = Len(CStr(CInt(Abs(value))))

  If Len(CStr(Abs(value))) > intPartLen Then
    DecimalPlaces = Mid(CStr(Abs(value)), intPartLen + 2)
  Else
    DecimalPlaces = "0"
  End If

End Function
```

It avoids common mistakes, so it is

- **locale-independent** - works with any decimal separator (it only assumes it is a single character)
- **preserves precision** - avoids subtraction, takes the result only from string representation

**Note:** those `Abs()` calls are really required (hint: `-0.1`)

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old post, there is a split function in VBA. Something like:

```
ArrayStr=split(cstr(dbl), ".")
```

Similar to the C# example. If wanting to run sql the Right and Left function could be embedded into the sql as well as cstr. Not sure how well it would run on a large data set.